# avoid overlapping of labels and arcs in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using chains to draw a simple Markov chain. I used `\draw` and `\path` to manually add arcs between nodes. But the labels and arcs overlap badly although I used `auto` location for labels. Is there a way to let Tikz do this automatically? Manually adjusting distances is possible but I believe Tikz is more powerful than I know.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right]
\node[state,on chain] (-2) {-2};
\node[state,on chain] (-1) {-1};
\node[state,on chain] (0) {0};
\node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+1) {+1};
\node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+2) {+2};

\draw[->] (-1) to node[auto] {$P(0)$}(-2);
\path[->] (-1) edge  [loop above] node[auto] {$P(1)$} ();
\draw[->] (-1) to node[auto] {$P(2)$}(0);
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right] node[auto] {$P(3)$}(+1);
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right] node[auto] {$P(4)$}(+2);

\draw[->] (+1) to node[above]{$1$} (0);
\draw[->] (+2) to[bend right] node[above]{$1$} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another approach.

In some cases when you have lots of nearby arcs, it is not a bad idea to put the labels on the arcs themselves. Here is an example from some previous work of mine:

[image: My example figure.]

With this in mind, here is how I would typeset your figure:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right]
  \tikzset{%
    in place/.style={
      auto=false,
      fill=white,
      inner sep=2pt,
    },
  }
  %
  \node[state,on chain]                   (-2) {$-2$};
  \node[state,on chain]                   (-1) {$-1$};
  \node[state,on chain]                   (0)  {$0$};
  \node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+1) {$+1$};
  \node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+2) {$+2$};
  \draw[->, auto]
    (-1) edge node[swap] {$P(0)$} (-2)
    (-1) edge[loop above] node {$P(1)$} ()
    (-1) edge node {$P(2)$} (0)
    (-1) edge[bend right=35] node[pos=0.7, in place] {$P(3)$} (+1)
    (-1) edge[bend right=35] node[pos=0.7, in place] {$P(4)$} (+2)
    (+1) edge node[swap] {$1$} (0)
    (+2) edge[bend right] node[swap] {$1$} (0)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Please note that

- I have grouped all your edges into one `\draw` operation;
- because of this, I can specify the `auto` option just once, and
- `swap` edges that appear on the "wrong" side, while
- the `in place` style (defined at the top of the figure) disables `auto` for a single node.

I also increased the bend angle a bit (from the default of `30` degrees) to give your arcs a bit more breathing room.

Finally, note that your numbers should be typeset in math mode. Compare the `$-1$` in my figure to the `-1` in your original.

[image: My rendering of your example.]

Comment: Nice! I like this.

Answer (score 10):

The `auto` option is not magic. Its effect depends on the current `direction`, so it cannot take surrounding drawings into effect. You will *have* to interfer manually, but there are ways to make this feel kind of automatic. The easiest way to fix this is to use an angle for the `bend right` style:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right]
\node[state,on chain] (-2) {-2};
\node[state,on chain] (-1) {-1};
\node[state,on chain] (0) {0};
\node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+1) {+1};
\node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+2) {+2};

\draw[->] (-1) to node[auto] {$P(0)$}(-2);
\path[->] (-1) edge  [loop above] node[auto] {$P(1)$} ();
\draw[->] (-1) to node[auto] {$P(2)$}(0);
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right=60] node[auto] {$P(3)$}(+1);
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right=60] node[auto] {$P(4)$}(+2);
%                           ^^^ change is here

\draw[->] (+1) to node[above]{$1$} (0);
\draw[->] (+2) to[bend right] node[above]{$1$} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields:
[image: result]

But i would suggest the following, for consistency (also, i like explicit positioning, but that is a matter of taste):

```
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right=30] node[below] {$P(3)$}(+1);
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right=50] node[below] {$P(4)$}(+2);
```

This yields [image: Result 2]

Answer (score 7):

Use the `auto` option globally and add `swap` to those nodes that end up on the wrong side.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,auto]
\node[state,on chain] (-2) {-2};
\node[state,on chain] (-1) {-1};
\node[state,on chain] (0) {0};
\node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+1) {+1};
\node[draw=red,fill=red,state,on chain] (+2) {+2};

\draw[->] (-1) to node[swap] {$P(0)$}(-2);
\path[->] (-1) edge  [loop above] node {$P(1)$} ();
\draw[->] (-1) to node {$P(2)$}(0);
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right] node[swap] {$P(3)$}(+1);
\draw[->] (-1) to[bend right=50] node[swap] {$P(4)$}(+2);

\draw[->] (+1) to node[swap]{$1$} (0);
\draw[->] (+2) to[bend right] node[swap]{$1$} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

For exercise: how to make OP code shorter and without overlapping of edges labels. With use of `quotes` library, and predefined `edge angle`, and reduced  labels' font size to `\footnotesize`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, chains, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
     bend angle = 45,
    start chain = going right,
every state/.append style = {on chain},
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
\node[state] (-2) {$-2$};
\node[state] (-1) {$-1$};
\node[state] (0)   {0};
\node[state,draw=red,fill=red] (+1) {$+1$};
\node[state,draw=red,fill=red] (+2) {$+2$};

\draw[->]   (-1) edge["$P(0)$"] (-2)
            (-1) edge[loop above,  "$P(1)$"] ()
            (-1) edge["$P(2)$"] (0)
            (-1) edge[bend right,"$P(3)$"] (+1)
            (-1) edge[bend right,"$P(4)$"] (+2)%change is here
            (+1) edge["$1$"]    (0)
            (+2) edge[bend right,"$1$"] (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the image of the automaton become:

[image]