# How can I add more bend to arrows using tikz?

Tags: graphics, tikz-arrows, graphs

How can I add more bend to the arrow going from a_2 ---> a_0 ?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm]

\node[initial,state,accepting] (S)      {$a_0$};
\node[state]         (a1) [right of=S]  {$a_1$};
\node[state]         (a2) [right of=a1] {$a_2$};
\node[state]         (a3) [right of=a2] {$a_3$};


\path[->] (S)  edge [loop above] node {0} (S);
\path[->] (S)  edge              node {1} (a1);
\path[->] (a1)  edge             node {0} (a2);
\path[->] (a3)  edge             node {0} (a2);
\path[->] (a3)  edge [loop above] node {1} (a3);
\path[->] (a2)  edge [bend left] node {0} (S);
\path[->] (a1)  edge [bend left] node {1} (a3);
\path[->] (a2)  edge [bend left] node {1} (a1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question is close related/duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352562/avoid-overlapping-of-labels-and-arcs-in-tikz ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352562/5763. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the angle at which the arc leaves as argument. Omitting the argument corresponds to the value of 30 degrees.

```
\path[->] (a2)  edge [bend left=50] node {0} (S);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm]

\node[initial,state,accepting] (S)      {$a_0$};
\node[state]         (a1) [right of=S]  {$a_1$};
\node[state]         (a2) [right of=a1] {$a_2$};
\node[state]         (a3) [right of=a2] {$a_3$};


\path[->] (S)  edge [loop above] node {0} (S);
\path[->] (S)  edge              node {1} (a1);
\path[->] (a1)  edge             node {0} (a2);
\path[->] (a3)  edge             node {0} (a2);
\path[->] (a3)  edge [loop above] node {1} (a3);
\path[->] (a2)  edge [bend left=50] node {0} (S);
\path[->] (a1)  edge [bend left] node {1} (a3);
\path[->] (a2)  edge [bend left] node {1} (a1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```